# How can I fix my formatting alignment problems?

Tags: c

The following code outputs a table that shows the score, mean score, deviation score and squared deviation.

A sample of the desired output (taken from the [homework assignment](http://cezeife.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/courses/60-140/assigns/assign3.pdf)):

[image]

On the answer key the columns are all aligned nicely but i couldn't figure out how to get the last line to align right so i need to know how to align the columns. All the other columns are aligned simply because i put a bunch of spaces in the printf code but i need to know how to align them with any input data because if the deviation score is longer than it will push everything over and will no longer be aligned.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float FindMean (float, float, float, float, float);
float Deviation (float, float);
float SqrdDev (float);

float main (void)
{
  float num1,num2,num3,num4,num5;
  float Meanscore;
  float DeviationScore1,DeviationScore2,DeviationScore3,DeviationScore4,DeviationScore5;
  float Square1,Square2,Square3,Square4,Square5;
  float Sum, variance, StandDev;

  printf("Please type the 5 test scores:  ");
  scanf("%f %f %f %f %f",&num1,&num2,&num3,&num4,&num5);
  Meanscore= FindMean (num1,num2,num3,num4,num5);

  DeviationScore1=Deviation(num1,Meanscore);
  DeviationScore2=Deviation(num2,Meanscore);
  DeviationScore3=Deviation(num3,Meanscore);
  DeviationScore4=Deviation(num4,Meanscore);
  DeviationScore5=Deviation(num5,Meanscore);

  Square1=SqrdDev(DeviationScore1);
  Square2=SqrdDev(DeviationScore2);
  Square3=SqrdDev(DeviationScore3);
  Square4=SqrdDev(DeviationScore4);
  Square5=SqrdDev(DeviationScore5);

  Sum=Square1+Square2+Square3+Square4+Square5;

  variance=Sum/5;
  StandDev=sqrt(variance);

  printf("Score   -   Mean Score =   Deviation Score   Squared Deviation\n");
  printf("(X)         (M)            (X-M)             (X-M)squared\n");
  printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num1,Meanscore,DeviationScore1,Square1);
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num2,Meanscore,DeviationScore2,Square2);
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num3,Meanscore,DeviationScore3,Square3);
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num4,Meanscore,DeviationScore4,Square4);
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num5,Meanscore,DeviationScore5,Square5);
  printf("                               Sum:               %.2f\n",Sum);
  printf("Variance=%.2f/5=%.2f\n",Sum,variance);
  printf("Standard deviation=SD=%.2f\n",StandDev);
  return 0;
}

float FindMean (float dig1,float dig2,float dig3,float dig4,float dig5)
{
  float Meanscore = (dig1+dig2+dig3+dig4+dig5)/5;
  return Meanscore;
}

float Deviation (float dig,float Mean)
{
  float Deviation = dig-Mean;
  return Deviation;
}

float SqrdDev (float Dev)
{
  float SqrdDev = Dev*Dev;
  return SqrdDev;
}
```

Comment: You can specify to `printf` the width of an output field like so: `%5.1f`.  Here, the field will be 5 characters (space padded) including the decimal dot.

Comment: When asking for help, you needn't paste your entire codebase, but only the relevant parts, i.e. remove all portions that aren't relevant to the question. In this case, only the ``printf`` lines would have sufficed.

Comment: Putting your desired output offsite in a PDF file isn't helpful. There's no reason you can't include it in your question here as text, even if you have to use spaces to get it to format so we can see the problem. Questions here need to be self-sufficient, meaning that all relevant content is **here**.

Comment: I have fixed up your question enough to not be closed (if you're lucky).  Please take time to read [ask] before you ask another question, because I probably won't see your next one, and someone else might not be so generous.

Comment: Agree with @KenWhite, having ***relevant*** code and information ***here*** is desirable, and will help people to answer your issues more quickly.  +1 for formatting and content by the way.   And the most relevant comment so far is from 5gon12eder, experiment with the padding available in "%10.2f" etc. to get all your columns in line.

Comment: the printf format parameter could use '/t' to use tab alignment, Plus each variable printed needs to have the desired number of chars specifically stated.  Then you would know exactly what the output will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding an example of what the comments have said;

Change this line: (similar for all of your printf lines)

```
  printf("%.0f          %.1f             %.1f                %.2f\n",num1,Meanscore,DeviationScore1,Square1);
```

To this, using format padding instead of embedded spaces:

```
  printf("%.0f %10.1f %10.1f %10.2f\n",num1,Meanscore,DeviationScore1,Square1);
```

***[More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)*** on format specifiers...